# QComboBox stylesheet left margin without side-effects

Tags: css, qt, qt-designer

I would like to add a 5px left margin outside a QComboBox.

How to do it in such a way that combobox height and the appearance of the dropdown button would remain untouched?

Without any margins:

```
QComboBox#commandComboBox  {
}
```

it looks like this:
[image: QtDesigner preview without any margins]

After adding a left margin:

```
QComboBox#commandComboBox  {
margin-left: 5px;
}
```

it looks like this:
[image: QtDesigner design view with a 5px left margin]

For some reason, combobox height changed. Also, now the item view contents stick out of the combobox frame.
To correct the second problem, I added a left padding:

```
QComboBox#commandComboBox  {
margin-left: 5px;
padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Now the item view contents are displayed correctly, however, the height is still wrong, the dropdown arrow button is shifted towards the right and the arrow itself is shifted towards the left.

it looks like this:
[image: QtDesigner preview]

Tried to specify negative left margin and padding for the arrow button, but this only messed it up further. It then lost the desktop manager style altogether and started to look blocky.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to alter stylesheets to add margin. You can just put a combo box inside a horizontal (or any other) layout and set left margin for this layout in Qt Designer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Though, I would like to have a small margin within the ComboBox, from which I could drag it around.

As an alternative, one could indeed create another widget to contain the ComboBox and horizontal box layout and make that widget draggable, instead.

Still, it should be possible with the stylesheets as well.